# TeXShop auto-deletion of certain groups of pasted in characters

Tags: math-mode, texshop, copy-paste

For my LaTeX equations I use Mathtype's excellent capability of copying equations as TeX code. My minor problem arises when I want numbered equations in LaTeX and also want to type the equation in Mathtype rather than directly in the TeX language.

When I copy/paste an equation from Mathtype it comes out as either:

```
\[{a^2} + {b^2} = {c^2}\]
```

or

```
$${a^2} + {b^2} = {c^2}$$
```

depending on the copy settings in Mathtype.

However in my document I will wrap this equation in the equation environment (to get numbering) as follows:

```
\begin{equation}
{a^2} + {b^2} = {c^2}
\label{eq:abc}
\end{equation}
```

I have to delete the `\[ \]` or `$$` manually as these don't belong in the equation environment. 
Is it possible that TeXShop detects these symbols **when pasted** automatically and either deletes them or replaces them with `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`?

So if I would just paste `\[` it would replace it with `\begin{equation}`.

I understand this question itself is (too) specific, but if a solution exists it could apply to other copy/paste rituals people may have.

### Edit:

I have found a solution that almost fits my needs in Mountain Lion's Text Replacement tool.

1. First enable the symbol and text substitution in the System Preferences.
2. Configure it such that `\[` is replaced by `\begin{equation}` and `\]` is replaced by `\end{equation}`.
   [image]
3. Copy/paste the formula from Mathtype into the TeXShop document.
4. Before compiling the code right click somewhere in the document and go to `Substitutions -> Show Substitutions`:
   [image]
5. The following window opens:
   [image]
   Check `Text Replacements` and click on `Replace All`.
6. Compile the document.

However, this does not substitute pasted in symbols automatically and requires an additional step. So I'm still looking for a "paste-time" method.

Comment: Well, if Mathtype gives you `{a^2}+{b^2}={c^2}` I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: Why not? It works flawlessly here...

Comment: If it adds those useless braces, I fear it adds others in places where they do *evil*.

Comment: I see. This might of course be the case, I haven't tested this systematically. But I've used the workflow now for 3 years in university and have not encountered any errors with it yet, so it suits my needs. Except for the inconvenience described in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, save the following file as "Latex (Texshop).tdl" into your "translator" folder.

```
MathType Output Translator 1.0: "Latex (Texshop)", "Daniel Wei 2013", language

include "LaTeX (base vars).tdl";
// redefinitions of base variables

var/"TranslatorName" = "Latex (Texshop)";
var/"TranslatorFileName" = "Latex (Texshop).tdl";

var/"BeginMathDisplay" = "\begin{equation}\label{}@n";
var/"EndMathDisplay" = "@n\end{equation}";

include "LaTeX (base rules).tdl";
```

Then in the Mathtype preference, just select "Latex (Texshop)" as your copying style.

Comment: And if you're worried about extra braces (like egreg), then you can tweak the tdl file to eliminate them. But I wouldn't recommend it.